How to use the data type from mysql in kotlin exposed
I'm trying to save an image to the database, for this I transfer it to byteArray and I have to save it to the blob data type that is in exposed. But byteArray doesn't fit there and I need the mediumBlob data type, which is not in exposed. How do I create a mediumBlob or how do I use it for my tables
I read the documentation but unfortunately I didn't find anything.
object Orgs : Table() {
val id = integer("id").autoIncrement()
val photoOrg = blob("photoOrg").nullable()
}


It's not recommended to save an image into the database.  Instead save the image in a directory and store its path as a text in the database table.

I think you can create your own column type from abstract class ColumnType() and describe all methods to convert values after reading or before saving. There is an example in this question How to add array Column type in Jetbrains Exposed
